# CakePHP - Can I $validate a field to require it to not have spaces? (it CAN have underscores and hyphens..etc)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

In CakePHP's model, can I $validate a field to require it to not have spaces or other special characters?

Specifically, I want them to type a name for their online folder - so it can have hyphens, underscores, etc, but not question marks, spaces...etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using this as a reference:  http://book.cakephp.org/view/1179/Custom-Validation-Rules

```
var $validate = array(
'login' => array(
    'rule' => '/^[a-z0-9]{3,}$/i',  
    'message' => 'Only letters and integers, min 3 characters'
));
```

You could set your rule to `/^[a-z0-9_\-\.]+$/i`  (regular expression) you just need to add the additional characters you want.

Not sure if you speak regular expressions, but that basically says the whole string `^...$` must contain only letters, numbers, underscores, hyphens (escaped), periods (escape perhaps unnecessary, but might match any character without it). `/i` makes it case-insensitive. `+` means you need one-or-more of those characters to be valid.

(Untested, but it should be straightforward enough.)

Comment: `.` need not be escaped inside a character group. You could make that `/^[a-z0-9_.-]+$/i`. :)

Comment: Right... if hyphen comes last, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Awesome - thanks.  I don't do much w/ regular expressions, but I know enough to look up the info - just didn't think to use em w/ Cake for some reason - thanks a lot.  (and thanks for the note deceze)